John the baptist and baptism of Jesus
In John1:33 John says he knows Jesus only after holy spirit came upon him after baptism.  But in mathew 3:14 john says he knows before baptism. why this contradiction?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

I think the OP may have misunderstood John 1:33 - look at the previous few verses:

29 The next day John saw Jesus coming toward him and said, “Look, the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world! 30 This is
He of whom I said, ‘A man who comes after me has surpassed me because
He was before me.’ 31 I myself did not know Him, but the reason I
came baptizing with water was that He might be revealed to Israel.”

That is, John appears to have been enlightened about Jesus as Messiah just before John saw Jesus coming toward John.  This is consistent with Matthew's account.

Matthew's account is worth quoting, with all the verses relevant to context. First, it is known from Luke's account that Elizabeth (John the Baptist's mother) and the virgin Mary were relatives - see Luke 1:24 to end of chapter. Note the reaction of the baby in Elizabeth's womb when Mary came close. John would have no recall of that, but his mother may well have told him, but it appears that it is entirely true that John did not "know" who Jesus was in the sense of him being the Son of God, until the point of him baptizing Jesus. He may have grown up knowing something of his relative, Jesus, who was only a few months younger than himself, but it is "knowing" in the biblical sense that matters, for the purpose of answering this question. Now, here are the relevant verses in Matthew's account, starting with John saying to the crowds coming to him:

"I indeed baptize you with water unto repentance: but he that cometh
after me is mightier than I, whose shoes I am not worthy to bear; he
shall baptize you with the Holy Ghost, and with fire... then cometh
Jesus from Galilee to Jordan unto John, to be baptized of him... And
Jesus, when he was baptized, went up straightway out of the water: and
lo, the heavens were opened unto him, and he saw the Spirit of God
descending like a dove, and lighting upon him. And lo a voice from
heaven, saying, This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased."
Matthew 3:11-17 A.V.

Now, compare that with the apostle John's account in John 1:33. First, John the Baptist denied being the foretold Messiah, the Christ, saying that that one would come after him, as he was preparing the way for that one. Again, it will be necessary to include surrounding verses to give the context:

"The next day John seeth Jesus coming unto him, and saith, Behold the
Lamb of God, which taketh away  the sin of the world. This is the one
of whom I said, After me cometh a man which is preferred before me:
for he was before me. And I knew him not... I saw the Spirit
descending from heaven like a dove, and it abode upon him. And I knew
him not: but he that sent me to baptize with water, the same said unto
me, Upon whom thou shalt see the Spirit descending, and remaining on
him, the same is he which baptizeth with the Holy Ghost. And I saw,
and bare record that this is the Son of God." John 1:29-34 A.V.

Note the sequence; John the Baptist would know Jesus as his relative, then he knew Jesus as the foretold Messiah, the Christ - the Lamb of God, then once he saw the Holy Spirit descend over Jesus at his baptism, he knew Jesus as the Son of God.
There is a progression of John's understanding as to who Jesus is, but it takes seeing the Spirit's descent, at Jesus' rising out of the waters of baptism, for John to declare unambiguously, "This is the Son of God!"
It is in what sense John "knows Jesus" that is key to seeing there is no contradiction between the two accounts, I suggest.

Is it a contradiction? Or is it confirmation?
Jesus' reputation precedes Him. He comes with people following Him so they understand who he is already, even before he receives the Holy Spirit.
John may be claiming like everyone else that this seems to be "the guy", and if so it was John that needed to be baptized by Jesus with fire and Spirit.
In John, when he says, "I myself did not know him" could mean that they had not previously met, even though they were cousins. There is no info given about John's life prior to the wilderness. He may not have realized that this man was his cousin, and he may be saying that this Messiah was a complete stranger to him. However when he sees him coming, he is able to recognize who he is.
It could also mean that John had not seen the Spirit on Jesus yet. Once he saw the Spirit descending on Him, then he "knew / could confirm" that this was actually the man that he was in fact expecting.
For me, I think it is probable that John had never met Jesus prior, even though they were related. I think that their being related and not knowing each other was a perfect reason for this dialogue to be recorded by John.
So John did not know Him, but he knew who he was when he saw Him coming.
